# How to understand the proof of E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y]?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I am studying probability and trying to follow an example in my textbook discussing expectation of the sum of random variables. But I'm having trouble following it.

$E[X+Y] = \int^∞_{-∞}\int^∞_{-∞}$(x+y)f(x,y)dxdy

$ = \int^∞_{-∞}\int^∞_{-∞}xf(x,y)dydx + \int^∞_{-∞}\int^∞_{-∞}yf(x,y)dxdy$

$ = \int^∞_{-∞}xf_X(x)dx + \int^∞_{-∞}yf_Y(y)dy$

$ = E[X] + E[Y]$

I am unsure how they obtain the third line down (the second equality). I understand $\int^∞_{-∞}f(x,y)dy = f_X(x)$ and vice versa for the marginal density function of Y. However, I'm a bit lost as to how they got rid of the double integral and not have to integrate x with respect to y as part of $xf(x,y)$ and likewise for y with respect to x.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: note that this result holds under more general assumption. (you are actually assuming here that the vector $(X, Y)$ is continuos)

Answer (score 9):

You answered yourself. $f_X (x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dy$ which is the marginal distribution $X$ of $(X,Y)$.

So 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x,y) dydx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dy}_{f_X(x)}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_X(x)dx = E[X]$$
and likewise for $Y$.

You can also see this for more general random variables (not only those with an absolutely continuous distribution). Given $X,Y:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ two random variables on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ where here $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of events of $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$E[X+Y] := \int_{\Omega} (X(\omega) + Y(\omega)) P(d\omega) = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega)P(d\omega)+\int_{\Omega} Y(\omega)P(d\omega) =E[X] + E[Y]$$
that is, the integral $\int_{\Omega} X(\omega) P(d\omega)$ is linear.

Comment: +1 and you can take the $x$ outside the integral because it does not depend on $y$

Comment: The x and y preceding the joint density functions are what are causing me confusion and how they are able to be taken outside the integral without integrating them. But a spark's just went in my head, and they are essentially treated like constants?

Comment: @Wolff Yes exactly, when integrating with respect to $y$ you can treat $x$ as a constant